# Silverlight - Bing Pushpin on click navigation

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, onclick, bing

I am wanting to add an on click even for a puship pin which will show a pop up windows eg.. Message.Show window.

Also, I want to have an OnCLick navigate too option.

Here is a snippet of my code.

```
Pushpin palmerstonN = new Pushpin();
            palmerstonN.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Brown);
            palmerstonN.Location = new GeoCoordinate(-40.3541236542693, 175.596991862399);
            palmerstonN.Content = "Arena Manawatu - Palmerston North";



this.map1.Children.Add(palmerstonN);
```

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A PushPin  has a MouseLeftButtonUp event that you can use to handle a click on the pushping. You could do something like:

```
Pushpin palmerstonN = new Pushpin();
        palmerstonN.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Brown);
        palmerstonN.Location = new GeoCoordinate(-40.3541236542693, 175.596991862399);
        palmerstonN.Content = "Arena Manawatu - Palmerston North";
        palmerstonN.MouseLeftButtonUp += new MouseButtonEventHandler(palmerstonN_MouseLeftButtonUp);

this.map1.Children.Add(palmerstonN);
}

void palmerstonN_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        Messabox.Show("My messagebox");
    }
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: I knew it would be simple. Cheers for that Tom. Also, I assume you mean MessageBox.Show("My Message");

Comment: Any idea on the Click for directions too? This would be for 7.0 now 7.1

Comment: Providing directions from Bing Maps is only available for Mango applications. When your app is upgraded you can use the BingMapsDirectionsTask (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.tasks.bingmapsdirectionstask_members(v=vs.92).aspx)

Comment: I was reading about that yesterday and in the progress of making required changes. Cheers Tom